# Javascript: Is there a way to make switch cases selectable in other functions?

Tags: javascript

This is the broken part of the code:

```
addSkillButton(stonewall);
```

My `object` argument called from other functions works fine. It goes to the switch statement, selects the correct case, and executes the code. However the problem I am having is with `addSkillButton()` function. I can manually enter a object and it will work fine, but my skill system is dynamic. I need it to pull the object name, based on the case number.

If you look at the code below, you'll notice both the skill `deepcut` & `stonewall` are on position 1. These are skills that pop up in a sub-menu as the user trys to upgrade. This works fine in opening, but selecting and adding the skill gets tricky, since I am not sure how I can tell javascript what case number was selected, so select that object name in position 1.

this is what I want it to say or do:

```
addSkillButton(Get Object in Position 1 from Case Number)
```

Here is my code:

> ```
> function radialSelector(object){
>    switch (object){
>       case strike:
>       radialSubMenuSkills("position1", deepcut);  
>       radialSubMenuSkills("position2", balancedstrike);   
>       radialSubMenuSkills("position3", fury);
>       break;
>       case defend:
>       radialSubMenuSkills("position1", stonewall);    
>       radialSubMenuSkills("position2", digin);    
>       radialSubMenuSkills("position3", holdtheline);
>       break;
>       default:
>       console.log("radialSelector() has set its switch statement to default")
>   }
>
>
>   $('#upgradeSkillsBar').on('click', '#position1', function(){
>       removeSkillButton(object);
>       addSkillButton(stonewall);
>       removeRadialSubMenu();
>   });
>
> }
> ```

Comment: Can you please arrange your question so it has a sensible logical order? "*This is the broken part*" is **not** a beginning of the story.

Comment: Your'e better of using arrays or array of objects and map. Switch is just a conditional like if, else, while, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an array.

```
var skills;
switch(object) {
    case strike:
        skills = [deepcut, balancedstrike, fury];
        break;
    case defend:
        skills = [stonewall, digin, holdtheline];
        break;
    default:
        throw new Error("Invalid condition");
}
for( var i=0, l=skills.length; i<l; i++) {
    radialSubMenuSkills("position"+(i+1), skills[i]);
}
$("#upgradeSkillsBar").on("click", "#position1", function() {
    removeSkillButton(object);
    addSkillButton(skills[0]);
    removeRadialSubMenu();
});
```